# Is every good enough space homotopy equivalent to a compact one?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Well, the question is more or less completely contained in the title. I found a partially related question on MO, namely [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22441/compactification-theorem-for-differentiable-manifolds), and googling around reveals an amazing theorem of Browder, Levine, and Livesay, which gives sufficient conditions for simply connected manifolds of high enough dimension to be homotopy equivalent to a compact manifold (actually necessary and sufficient to be an interior of a compact manifold with boundary).

However, I am not concerned with the desired compact space being a manifold or otherwise not pathological, and wouldn't mind putting additional restrictions on the original space (like having finitely many connected components or finitely generated homology).

I would appreciate any help.

UPD: edited the question just to bring it to the front page again.

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient that it be (1) the homotopy type of a CW-complex and (2) have cohomology groups bounded above and of finite type.

Comment: (Of course this is not necessary, since many compact spaces fail (1))